# how to list vignettes in a package in a README or related

Tags: r, package, r-markdown, vignette, pkgdown

In several packages, most recently the `matlib` package on github, https://github.com/friendly/matlib,
I have a README.{md,Rmd} file that says something like

> A small collection of vignettes is now available.  Use `browseVignettes("matlib")` to see them.

I'd like to replace or add to this in the README with a list of the vignette names and their titles.

The closest I can come to the info I want in the README is the result of `> vignette(package= "matlib")` that looks like this:

```
 Vignettes in package ‘matlib’:

 eigen-ex1               Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors: Properties
                         (source, html)
 eigen-ex2               Eigenvalues: Spectral Decomposition (source,
                         html)
 det-ex2                 Evaluation of determinants (source, html)
 ginv                    Generalized inverse (source, html)
 gramreg                 Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization and Regression
                         (source, html)
 inv-ex1                 Inverse of a matrix (source, html)
 inv-ex2                 Matrix inversion by elementary row operations
                         (source, html)
 det-ex1                 Properties of determinants (source, html)
 linear-equations        Solving Linear Equations (source, html)
```

But I want to capture the result of this in a chunk or sth I can use directly in the README. If I build the package site with `pkgdown`, I get the resulting links to vignettes under **Articles*, but I still don't have the list of vignette names and titles as anything I can use directly.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, `tools::getVignetteInfo()` gives me what I want

```
> vinfo <- tools::getVignetteInfo("ggplot2")

> vinfo
     Package   Dir                            Topic                
[1,] "ggplot2" "C:/R/R-3.6.3/library/ggplot2" "ggplot2-specs"      
[2,] "ggplot2" "C:/R/R-3.6.3/library/ggplot2" "extending-ggplot2"  
[3,] "ggplot2" "C:/R/R-3.6.3/library/ggplot2" "ggplot2-in-packages"
     File                      Title                      
[1,] "ggplot2-specs.Rmd"       "Aesthetic specifications" 
[2,] "extending-ggplot2.Rmd"   "Extending ggplot2"        
[3,] "ggplot2-in-packages.Rmd" "Using ggplot2 in packages"
     R                       PDF                       
[1,] "ggplot2-specs.R"       "ggplot2-specs.html"      
[2,] "extending-ggplot2.R"   "extending-ggplot2.html"  
[3,] "ggplot2-in-packages.R" "ggplot2-in-packages.html"
>
```